# Connect direct with splunk

Tags: splunk, syslog, rsyslog, syslog-ng, connect-direct

I've have an issue, 
I have to use data from connect direct, directly to Splunk Enterprise or Syslog-ng, It's possible?

Regards.

Comment: I have this issue as well. I found the statistics logs, and those would be amazing to have in splunk.

Comment: What format does Connect:Direct send its logs in? Is it [syslog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog) (or very similar)? If it speaks syslog, send them to your syslog collector (rsyslog, syslog-ng, etc), and then forward from there to Splunk (via UF or HEC)